# Extension support browser.runtime.connectNative

Tags: runtime, native, firefox-addon-webextensions

We want to use extension replace with plugin, but we need use extension to download files and launch the file such as exe file.
Is there a method to do?
As pages said, Firefox extension will compate with Chrome's extension, we found Firefox support most APIs, but do not support runtime.connectNative() and some native APIs.
Does Firefox support them? If support, when will support? And how to support Native's extension?

Answer (score 0):

The native messaging API is not yet implemented in Firefox WebExtensions, but it's on the future roadmap.

In the meantime, you can use the older SDK API [system/child_process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process) to communicate with external binaries over a pipe interface.

Also, if you want to contribute an implementation of native messaging to Firefox WebExtensions, I will happily introduce you to people who can help with mentoring and code review.

Comment: Thanks your answer, about the SDK API system/child_process , is it OK for later usage? Or will replaced by the native messaging API ?

Comment: Eventually, WebExtensions will be the only API, so native messaging is definitely the long-term solution. But the SDK is not going away for a while yet.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox WebExtension API will support `connectNative()` from version 50 on. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/connectNative) is already available. You can try out the API using Firefox Developer Edition 50.